# Automatically enter date into cell when data is PASTED into other column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a VBA code that will automatically enter the current date in column A when data is **copy&pasted** into columns C-L in the same row.

I figured out how to automatically enter the date when I manually write data into column C, but this will **not work** when I paste data in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
With Target(1, -1)
.Value = Date
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End If

End Sub
```

I would also like the date to automatically appear when I enter data into other columns other than C (e.g. D-L).

Thank you all!

Comment: "I figured out how to automatically enter the date when I manually write data into column C" - it would help your question if you included the code you wrote for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this - just update the range being checked:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:L"))
    
    'any tracked cells in Target range?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 
        Set rng = rng.Entirerow    
        For Each rw In rng.Rows   'loop updated rows
            rw.Cells(1) = Date    'put date in ColA
        Next rw
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a VBA solution you seek, then you can specify the entire range C:L in your Private Sub.  The following code assumes you only want to fill in cells that are blank in column A, starting from A2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LastRow as Long
If Not Intersect(Range("C:L"), Target) Is Nothing Then

LastRow = Range("C:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = Date

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked for _enter the current date in column A when data is copy&pasted into columns C-L **in the same row**._

Comment: @chris neilsen you're right!  I assumed (wrongly?) that the data would have been contiguous and not over-written.  Thanks for the heads' up.